# How to quickly switch between the different Python executables on my Mac?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

Can anyone tell me how I can quickly switch between the below Python executables on my Mac?

I want to be able to stipulate in one particular virtual environment to use the Enthought Canopy executable which I need for psiTurk

- "Native to computer" /usr/local/bin/python
- "Local to virtual environment" /Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/psiturktestfive
- "Enthought Canopy" /Users/brendan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
- ".bash_profile" /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Is there a simple terminal command to do it?

Currently I am only able to make my machine use the Enthought Canpy version if I edit my .bash_profile but once I activate a new virtual environment for a project is switches to the virtual environments local python executable

Any help is as always, much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The below error is what i recieve when I try to use `virtualenv -p /Users/brendan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python canopy`

```
localhost:workspace brendan$ virtualenv -p /Users/brendan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python canopy
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Users/brendan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
Using base prefix '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents'
New python executable in canopy/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/canopy/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable canopy/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace' (should be u'/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/canopy')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
localhost:workspace brendan$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `virtualenv` by using:

```
virtualenv -p /Users/brendan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python canopy
```

and then do

```
source canopy/bin/activate
```

(if you are on Unix and use Bash).

Virtualenv can install with `pip install virtualenv`, or follow instruction on the [home page](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I did not know that I could create a virtual environment with a different version of Python. Unfortunately when I try your solution I get the above error (see EDIT).

Comment: Can you start /Users/brendan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python (clicking or commandline)?

Comment: Yes, I can start it both ways

Comment: [You cannot create a Enthought Canopy virtual environment using virtualenv.][1]  
  [1]: https://support.enthought.com/entries/21802240-Use-venv-not-virtualenv-with-Canopy-Python